# how to set a variable inside of a callback function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, cordova, callback, web-storage

i am testing [Phonegap Web Storage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage) for a small project:

```
var listsCount = 0;

tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM list WHERE id = ?", [id], successGetList, errorGetList );

function successGetList(tx, results){
    listsCount = results.rows.length; // this will be 2, in my case
}

function errorGetList(err){
    console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

console.log(listsCount); // this will show 0, instead of 2
```

the issue i'm having is that `listsCount` doesn't get set inside the `successGetList` method. Even if i return it there.

any ideas on how can i set that variable inside of `successGetList` function ?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function) (Granted, this not AJAX, but the same asynchronous behavior applies.)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi This is not asking about `return` either. You're right that the answer there should point the right direction, but maybe that's too much for this particular question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does get set, but your `console.log` call is being fired before that (that's how asynchronous code works!). Just use the value from the callback. If you need, call another function from there, and pass your data to it.

Comment: `Just use the value from the callback`, how?

Comment: I mean use `results.rows.length` from inside `successGetList`, or call another function from there and pass it. The exact answer will depend on what you want to do with the value...

Comment: got it. didn't notice that the callback is asynchronous. thanks